# Call Eigen GEMM over externally allocated data

Tags: c++, eigen, matrix-multiplication, allocation, eigen3

Eigen has amazingly fast GEMM implementation so i want to use it inside my pet project tensor library. 
If i understand correctly it's possible via Eigen::Map. I wrote simple example and defined `EIGEN_NO_MALLOC` to make sure that there are no unwanted allocations.

It's works well with simple matrix multiplication like `C += A * B`.
But unfortunately it cannot handle `C += alpha * A * B` (GEMM like) situation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define EIGEN_NO_MALLOC
#include "Eigen/Core"

int main()
{
    using Scalar = float;
    using namespace Eigen;
    std::vector<Scalar> aDat = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<Scalar> bDat = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<Scalar> cDat = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    Map<Matrix<Scalar, -1, -1, RowMajor>, Unaligned> a(aDat.data(), 2, 2);
    Map<Matrix<Scalar, -1, -1, RowMajor>, Unaligned> b(bDat.data(), 2, 2);
    Map<Matrix<Scalar, -1, -1, RowMajor>, Unaligned> c(cDat.data(), 2, 2);

    //Ok
    c.noalias() += a * b;

    //Assertion `false && "heap allocation is forbidden.....
    c.noalias() += 2 * a * b;

    return 0;
}
```

`c.noalias() += 2 * a * b;` gives me following runtime error

```
a.out: path_to_eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:129: void Eigen::internal::check_that_malloc_is_allowed(): Assertion `false && "heap allocation is forbidden (EIGEN_NO_MALLOC is defined)"' failed.
```

Is it possible to call `c.noalias() += someScalar * a * b;` without allocations?

PS My eigen version is `3.3.2`, `gcc` version is `7.2.0`

Sorry for my poor English

Comment: Try adding `__attribute__((aligned (32)))` to the `vector`

Comment: @Matt I'm not good with "attribute" stuff =(. Should it looks like `std::vector<Scalar> __attribute__((aligned (32))) aDat`, etc? I just added attribute between type and name of variable for each vector and my example gives me same error.

Comment: @Matt Having the `std::vector` object aligned will make no difference at all (this has no influence on the data that is actually used for the product).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug introduced by a small-size optimization. For products `(KxM)*(MxN)` where `K+M+N < EIGEN_GEMM_TO_COEFFBASED_THRESHOLD` (which by default is `20`), Eigen switches to a lazy product implementation, which apparently thinks evaluating into a temporary is a good idea. Your example will actually work fine, e.g. for a `5x5 * 5x10` product.

I filed a bug for that issue: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1562

If you want a quick work-around, define `-D EIGEN_GEMM_TO_COEFFBASED_THRESHOLD=1`, this will always use the *big matrix*-GEMM implementation.

On the other hand, if you know your matrix size at compile time, you should better use the corresponding fixed-size type (`Matrix<Scalar, 2, 2, RowMajor>` in your case).

Comment: thank you for answer! I'll check your workaround tomorrow. My pet library designed to be used with quite big matrices. Is it possible to apply workaround localy? In other words, is it possible to apply it only for several lines inside my .h file?

Comment: just tried to add `#define EIGEN_GEMM_TO_COEFFBASED_THRESHOLD 1` before eigen include - same error
Using big matrices helps me - everything works! But i want to keep `EIGEN_NO_MALLOC` inside my tests and i have tests with small matrices (because it's good idea to have small tests), so it's not very good case for me.
Anyway thank you for explanation!

Comment: That workaround seems to work only on the development-branch ("default")  You can't use that define function-locally, it may work locally per compilation unit (but I would not rely on that). If you know that your matrices are likely small, you can directly write `c.noalias() += 2 * a.lazyProduct(b);` (this will be bad, if you occasionally get big matrices, however.)